# Retrieve the most recent person record added to an account

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to build a table of Contact IDs (Primary Keys) of the most recently created records assigned to each Account of a certain type in our Salesforce org.

Working in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, I'm trying to build a sample list that I can setup to update automatically so the records I'm testing against are never stale. I only need one example from each account to do my testing. Since I want to make sure the record isn't stale, I want to select the most recent record assigned to each Account.

Every Contact is assigned to one and only one Account. The Account ID lives as a foreign key on the Contact Record. The created date of the Contact is also a field on the Contact record.

The Sample list needs to contain the email address, ContactID, and the name of the Management Company, which lives on the Account record.

I figured doing a directional JOIN toward the Account table would do the trick, but that didn't work. I figure that's because there's nothing distinguishing which record to pick.

This is what I've got for code, which is pretty useless...

```
SELECT
    C.Email AS Email,
    C.Id AS Id18,
    C.AccountID AS AccountID,
    A.Management_Company AS ManagementCompany
FROM
    ENT.Contact_Salesforce_DE AS C 
    RIGHT JOIN ENT.Account_Salesforce_DE AS A ON C.AccountID = A.Id
WHERE
    A.RecordTypeId = '1234567890ABCDEFGH' AND
    A.Management_Company IS NOT NULL AND
    C.Email IS NOT NULL
```

The syntax checks out, but I get a system error every time I run it.

Marketing Cloud runs on an older version of SQL Server, so some more recent query functions won't always work.

And yes, I'm a relative noob to SQL. Won't surprise me if this has a really simple solution, but I couldn't find another entry describing the solution, so...

Comment: Can you add the specific error you are getting to your question, please?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't. Marketing Cloud doesn't give specifics when there's an error. It just says "system error"

Answer (score 0):

If I followed you correctly, you want to pull out the latest contact associated with each account.

On database servers that do not support window function (which seems to be the case of your RDBMS), one typical solution is to add a special condition to the `JOIN`. This `NOT EXISTS` condition uses a subquery to ensure that the record being picked in the child table is the most recent one (in other words : there is no child record with a highest creation date than the one being joined) :

```
SELECT
    c.Email AS Email,
    c.Id AS Id18,
    c.AccountID AS AccountID
FROM
    ENT.Account_Salesforce_DE AS a 
    INNER JOIN ENT.Contact_Salesforce_DE AS c 
        ON c.AccountID = a.Id
        AND c.email IS NOT NULL
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT 1
            FROM ENT.Contact_Salesforce_DE AS c1
            WHERE 
                c1.email IS NOT NULL 
                AND c1.AccountID = a.Id 
                AND c1.CreatedDate > c.CreatedDate
        )
WHERE
    A.RecordTypeId = '1234567890ABCDEFGH' 
    AND A.Management_Company IS NOT NULL
```